# Force Array to Be Value Type or Workaround C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, reference

I've encountered an interesting problem. So I know arrays in C# are reference types. I've found that I actually need it to act like a value type. I have a C++ queue that I'm pulling data from in a C# app that has a byte[] parameter. The data pulled is stored in that variable and then I append that byte[] array to a List. Since array's are reference in C#, each item in the list takes on the value of whatever the last pulled data is. My first thought is to do a "new" on each data pull but that sounds costly and bad programming practice. Is there a workaround I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have several different arrays, the correct approach is to simply create multiple arrays, rather than re-using a single array when you want to have multiple.

To create a type that has the semantics that you copy the entirety of its data whenever you assign it to another variable wouldn't even save you the effort of creating multiple arrays, as you'd still be doing that when you copied them.

Comment: Let's say I go with this approach and effectively do a new on each pull from the queue. Should I do anything with GC or leave it to the CLR to handle it? I'm talking tons of array objects

Comment: @Seapoe You don't really have a choice either way.  The GC manages managed objects, you're creating a managed object, therefore, the GC will manage it.